# Adding up letters to form words

Tags: javascript, android, string, keystroke

Not sure I worded my question correctly but I tried.

I currently have key strokes being recorded  within some JavaScript and have converted to them to their character values. I have also exported the variable that holds the letter into java.

```
   public void receiveKeyStroke(String keyStroke){
       Log.i(TAG, keyStroke);

    }
```

My question is how do I add the letter to another Variable eg a String and have them add on each time. The idea is if I type dog in the key pad, dog will then be in this variable that is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your keyStroke is being received as a String too. You can use a static variable inside the function `receiveKeyStroke` and append the incoming keyStroke every time the function is called. Static variables retain their values during multiple calls. For example, the variable `word` will contain the complete word below.

```
public void receiveKeyStroke(String keyStroke){
   static String word;
   word = word + keyStroke;
   Log.i(TAG, keyStroke);
}
```

This code might not be efficient though and you can improve it by changing `String` to `StringBuffer` and/or using a class level variable instead of a static one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare the variable outside of the method in my class:

```
private String inputText = "";
```

The next step was to add the letter to my string:

```
inputText += keyStroke;
```

This then allows me to add up the letters and form words.

Answer (score 0):

public void receiveKeyStroke(String keyStroke){

```
   Log.i(TAG, keyStroke);``

   keyStroke += "is here";
```

}